# How to display search results live

Tags: php, html, ajax

Here i have simple search engine to search usernames. when people type username i want them to see results below search box and have them taken to search page only after they hit enter (like facebooks search engine).

```
html

<div class="search">
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="Search" size="50">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</div>
```

php (search.php)

```
<?php
require 'includes/connection.php';

$term = $_GET['Search'];

$query_ver = "select * from Members where Name like '%$term%'";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_ver);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $name = $row['Name'];

}

echo $name;

?>
```

so is there a way to display $name below search box only with php and html

Comment: You need to use ajax for that. So you can do that with html+php+javascript. Look at this article as simple guide http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

Comment: What @MarkS said.  But you also need to research bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="search">
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="search" size="50" class="search">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = \'search=\'+ searchid;
if(searchid!=\'\')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "result.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find(\'.name\').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $(\'#searchid\').val(decoded);
});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$(\'#searchid\').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
});
</script>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST)
{
    $q = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    $strSQL_Result = mysql_query("select id,name,email from live_search where name like '%$q%' or email like '%$q%' order by id LIMIT 5");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($strSQL_Result))
    {
        $username   = $row['name'];
        $email      = $row['email'];
        $b_username = '<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
        $b_email    = '<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
        $final_username = str_ireplace($q, $b_username, $username);
        $final_email = str_ireplace($q, $b_email, $email);
        ?>
            <div class="show" align="left">
                <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/27301_312848892150607_553904419_n.jpg" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" /><span class="name"><?php echo $final_username; ?></span>&nbsp;<br/><?php echo $final_email; ?><br/>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

> for reference here is good solution

[LINK1](http://ninetofive.me/blog/build-a-live-search-with-ajax-php-and-mysql)
[LINK2](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-integrate-live-search-in-php-and-mysql-with-jquery_309.html)